# What is Paypal's Recurring Payment Profile RPSTATE parameter?

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing, name-value

PayPal's Recurring Payment Profile inquiry will return a string of parameters similar to any other PayPal "RESULT". Most of these are either self-evident, or are explained in the docs.

I can not find any explanation of `RPSTATE`. I am troubleshooting an application, and I would like to eliminate this string parameter from my check list.

**Does anybody here know what `RPSTATE` points to?**

Here is the parameter in the context of PayPal's returned string (source is PayPal's sample return statement, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/recurring-billing/#using-the-sdk-to-perform-recurring-tasks):

```
RESULT=0&RPREF=R2X52F7AA3E9&PROFILEID=RT0000000278&STATUS=ACTIVE&CREATIONDATE=0410201
5&PROFILENAME=123456789/*&START=04112015&TERM=0&NEXTPAYMENT=12112019&PAYPERIOD=DAYS
&LASTCHANGED=12102019&RPSTATE=6&NEXTPAYMENTNUM=1706&COMMENT1=Pass Comment&
FREQUENCY=1&TENDER=C&AMT=1.00&ACCT=4012XXXXXXXX1881&EXPDATE=1018&AGGREGATEAMT=1705.00
&AGGREGATEOPTIONALAMT=5.00&MAXFAILPAYMENTS=0&NUMFAILPAYMENTS=0&RETRYNUMDAYS=0&
BILLTOEMAIL=customer@email.com&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=Lord&MBILLTOMIDDLENAME=Middle&
BILLTOLASTNAME=Nikkon&BILLTOSTREET=123 Main St&BILLTOCITY=Omaha&BILLTOSTATE=NE
&BILLTOZIP=12345&BILLTOCOUNTRY=US&BILLTOPHONENUM=403-234-5678&SHIPTOFIRSTNAME=Lord
&SHIPTOMIDDLENAME=Middle&SHIPTOLASTNAME=Nikkon&SHIPTOSTREET=123 Testing
&SHIPTOCITY=San Jose&SHIPTOSTATE=CA&SHIPTOZIP=67890&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=US
```

Tldr: `RPSTATE=6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's mostly redundant with the `STATUS` field and you can ignore it

```
6,7 :: active
8 :: matured or finished?
11,12 :: cancelled
>= 1000 :: deactivated
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense in context. Are you able to share your source for for the active/matured/finished/etc codes?

Comment: I may or may not have referenced a copy of the Payflow gateway's source code from over 10 years ago.